# How to adjust this little script from IPv4 to IPv6?

Tags: awk, ipv6, whois

This script is checking who is knocking on the phone line and displays the address by whois of the person who wanted to knock on the phone line.

```
awk '{

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)

      if ($i ~ /^SRC=/)
          print substr($i, 5)

}' /var/log/syslog | sort -u | while read ip; #former file was: /etc/sysconfig/syslog

do
    printf ' INVALID STATE ' && printf ' === %s ===\n' "$ip"
    whois "$ip" >> output-001.txt;
done
```

This script works with IPv4 addresses, but not IPv6 -- how would I need to adjust it to work for both? I need the whois address of everyone who tries to knock on the phone line.

The contents of `output-001.txt` is:

> Unknown AS-number or unknown ip-network. please upgrade this program (whois).

I think this is because of the firewall of the provider blocking the script. What can I add to get through the firewall of the provider (unitymedia)?

For roaima - the result of summer 2016 was looking like here in output-001.txt :

```
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32'

% Abuse contact for '2a02:908::/32' is 'abuse@umkbw.de'

inet6num:       2a02:908::/32
netname:        DE-KNRW-20090121
country:        DE
org:            ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
status:         ALLOCATED-BY-RIR
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-routes:     UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-domains:    UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-01-21T09:36:59Z
last-modified:  2016-04-14T09:45:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
remarks:        Contact data for any network abuse/spam/security issue:
remarks:        abuse@unitymedia.de
remarks:        =======================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)

organisation:   ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
org-name:       Unitymedia NRW GmbH
org-type:       LIR
address:        Aachener Str. 746 - 750
address:        50933
address:        Koeln
address:        GERMANY
phone:          +49 2273 605 8567
fax-no:         +49 2273 5947 2251
fax-no:         +49 2273 605 4339
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@umkbw.de
admin-c:        SB666-RIPE
admin-c:        JK8125-RIPE
admin-c:        MH3982-RIPE
mnt-ref:        RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-ref:        UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
abuse-c:        UKAD1-RIPE
created:        2004-04-17T11:09:24Z
last-modified:  2016-03-11T12:07:57Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Administration
address:        Unitymedia Group
                Aachener Strasse 746-750
                50933 Koeln
                Germany
admin-c:        EM572-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMAC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2009-09-03T09:14:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Technical Contact
address:        Unitymedia KabelBW GmbH
address:        Michael-Schumacher-Strasse 1
address:        50170 Kerpen
address:        DE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         MH3982-RIPE
tech-c:         SJ3189-RIPE
tech-c:         EM10466-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMTC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2014-11-19T06:01:06Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '2a02:908:8000::/33AS20825'

route6:         2a02:908:8000::/33
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS20825
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2016-02-11T13:24:04Z
last-modified:  2016-02-11T13:25:00Z
source:         RIPE

% Information related to '2a02:908:8000::/33AS6830'

route6:         2a02:908:8000::/33
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS6830
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2016-02-11T14:58:12Z
last-modified:  2016-02-11T14:58:12Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.87.4 (BLAARKOP)


% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32'

% Abuse contact for '2a02:908::/32' is 'abuse@umkbw.de'

inet6num:       2a02:908::/32
netname:        DE-KNRW-20090121
country:        DE
org:            ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
status:         ALLOCATED-BY-RIR
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-routes:     UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-domains:    UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-01-21T09:36:59Z
last-modified:  2016-04-14T09:45:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
remarks:        Contact data for any network abuse/spam/security issue:
remarks:        abuse@unitymedia.de
remarks:        =======================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)

organisation:   ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
org-name:       Unitymedia NRW GmbH
org-type:       LIR
address:        Aachener Str. 746 - 750
address:        50933
address:        Koeln
address:        GERMANY
phone:          +49 2273 605 8567
fax-no:         +49 2273 5947 2251
fax-no:         +49 2273 605 4339
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@umkbw.de
admin-c:        SB666-RIPE
admin-c:        JK8125-RIPE
admin-c:        MH3982-RIPE
mnt-ref:        RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-ref:        UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
abuse-c:        UKAD1-RIPE
created:        2004-04-17T11:09:24Z
last-modified:  2016-03-11T12:07:57Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Administration
address:        Unitymedia Group
                Aachener Strasse 746-750
                50933 Koeln
                Germany
admin-c:        EM572-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMAC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2009-09-03T09:14:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Technical Contact
address:        Unitymedia KabelBW GmbH
address:        Michael-Schumacher-Strasse 1
address:        50170 Kerpen
address:        DE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         MH3982-RIPE
tech-c:         SJ3189-RIPE
tech-c:         EM10466-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMTC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2014-11-19T06:01:06Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '2a02:908:8000::/33AS20825'

route6:         2a02:908:8000::/33
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS20825
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2016-02-11T13:24:04Z
last-modified:  2016-02-11T13:25:00Z
source:         RIPE

% Information related to '2a02:908:8000::/33AS6830'

route6:         2a02:908:8000::/33
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS6830
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2016-02-11T14:58:12Z
last-modified:  2016-02-11T14:58:12Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.87.4 (ANGUS)


Unbekannte AS-Nummer oder unbekanntes IP-Netzwerk. Bitte führen Sie ein Upgrade dieses Programms durch.
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32'

% Abuse contact for '2a02:908::/32' is 'abuse@umkbw.de'

inet6num:       2a02:908::/32
netname:        DE-KNRW-20090121
country:        DE
org:            ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
status:         ALLOCATED-BY-RIR
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-lower:      UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-routes:     UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-domains:    UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-01-21T09:36:59Z
last-modified:  2016-04-14T09:45:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered
remarks:        Contact data for any network abuse/spam/security issue:
remarks:        abuse@unitymedia.de
remarks:        =======================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax:  49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)

organisation:   ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
org-name:       Unitymedia NRW GmbH
org-type:       LIR
address:        Aachener Str. 746 - 750
address:        50933
address:        Koeln
address:        GERMANY
phone:          +49 2273 605 8567
fax-no:         +49 2273 5947 2251
fax-no:         +49 2273 605 4339
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@umkbw.de
admin-c:        SB666-RIPE
admin-c:        JK8125-RIPE
admin-c:        MH3982-RIPE
mnt-ref:        RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-ref:        UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
abuse-c:        UKAD1-RIPE
created:        2004-04-17T11:09:24Z
last-modified:  2016-03-11T12:07:57Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Administration
address:        Unitymedia Group
                Aachener Strasse 746-750
                50933 Koeln
                Germany
admin-c:        EM572-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMAC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2009-09-03T09:14:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Technical Contact
address:        Unitymedia KabelBW GmbH
address:        Michael-Schumacher-Strasse 1
address:        50170 Kerpen
address:        DE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         MH3982-RIPE
tech-c:         SJ3189-RIPE
tech-c:         EM10466-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMTC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2014-11-19T06:01:06Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '2a02:908:8000::/33AS20825'
```

Comment: When you say "not working", is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: @diametralpitch - No, only the output is restricted. There are no addresses delivered by whois-query. Instead only the address of my provider appears in the list of output-001.txt - it seems that there is the firewall of provider which prevents detailed whois-queries of knockers. - I was thinking it has to do with ipv6, but now I guess it is the firewall ... - how can I bridge through the firewall ?

Comment: That may be a question you should ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Please provide some examples of the IPv4 addresses that worked, and IPv6 addresses that don't. Failing that, please provide examples of the source lines containing IPv4 addresses that work and IPv6 addresses that don't.

Comment: @dschinn1001 I'd be happy to attempt to help you with this, but without seeing some of the data you're trying to process it's impossible. Please review (and respond to) my earlier comment of 31st December.

Comment: @roaima - when script ran earlier in last summer, only the addresses of unitymedia were listed. But now the addresses of unitymedia (by whois) are not listed any more. In 2012 and before 2012 all addresses (by whois) of every knocker were listed in output-001.txt.

Comment: Or is there a conflict (bug?) between program whois and IPv6 - protocol of modems and of servers ? Is this because of subnet ID ? - as described here: https://www.arin.net/knowledge/ipv6_info_center.html

Comment: For the THIRD time: without some source data we cannot help you!

Comment: @roaima - have put into question a visible result for you, as it was in last summer 2016.

Comment: Do you understand what I'm asking? Without some source data we cannot help you!

Comment: @dschinn1001 we need to see your *input data* not your output. It is impossible to help you parse something if you don't show us what you are trying to parse.

Comment: @terdon - am currently working out, if I can reproduce an input (after 2012) ... have installed rsyslogd - but I think it is because of different ip-format between IPv6 and IPv4 - this is why there is a blackout with my script. please be patient, I try to find a suiting input-failure ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the first IPv6 address from your output file, if I just

```
$whois 2a02:908::/32
```

I am getting results as expected with no whois error (Unknown AS-number or unknown ip-network. please upgrade this program (whois).)

```
$whois 2a02:908::/32
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32'

% Abuse contact for '2a02:908::/32' is 'abuse@umkbw.de'

inet6num:       2a02:908::/32
netname:        DE-KNRW-20090121
country:        DE
org:            ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
status:         ALLOCATED-BY-RIR
remarks:        Contact data for any network abuse/spam/security issue:
remarks:        abuse@unitymedia.de
remarks:        =======================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: 49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: 49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-lower:      UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-routes:     UNITYMEDIA-MNT
mnt-domains:    UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-01-21T09:36:59Z
last-modified:  2016-08-25T14:02:54Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

organisation:   ORG-iGCK3-RIPE
org-name:       Unitymedia NRW GmbH
org-type:       LIR
address:        Aachener Str. 746 - 750
address:        50933
address:        Koeln
address:        GERMANY
phone:          +49 2273 605 8567
fax-no:         +49 2273 5947 2251
fax-no:         +49 2273 605 4339
admin-c:        SB666-RIPE
admin-c:        JK8125-RIPE
admin-c:        MH3982-RIPE
abuse-c:        UKAD1-RIPE
mnt-ref:        RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-ref:        UNITYMEDIA-MNT
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@umkbw.de
mnt-by:         RIPE-NCC-HM-MNT
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2004-04-17T11:09:24Z
last-modified:  2016-08-25T14:03:26Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Administration
address:        Unitymedia Group
                Aachener Strasse 746-750
                50933 Koeln
                Germany
admin-c:        EM572-RIPE
tech-c:         UMTC-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMAC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2009-09-03T09:14:51Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

role:           Unitymedia Technical Contact
address:        Unitymedia KabelBW GmbH
address:        Michael-Schumacher-Strasse 1
address:        50170 Kerpen
address:        DE
admin-c:        UMAC-RIPE
tech-c:         MH3982-RIPE
tech-c:         SJ3189-RIPE
tech-c:         EM10466-RIPE
nic-hdl:        UMTC-RIPE
remarks:        =====================================================
remarks:        Contact data for any legal/law enforcement inquiries:
remarks:        Auskunft.UM (at) unitymedia.de
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 3220 (primary)
remarks:        Fax: +49 2273 5947 2251 (backup)
remarks:        =====================================================
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@unitymedia.de
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-07-10T11:13:10Z
last-modified:  2014-11-19T06:01:06Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32AS20825'

route6:         2a02:908::/32
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS20825
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2009-01-23T22:05:02Z
last-modified:  2009-07-10T15:01:59Z
source:         RIPE

% Information related to '2a02:908::/32AS6830'

route6:         2a02:908::/32
descr:          Unitymedia
origin:         AS6830
mnt-by:         UNITYMEDIA-MNT
created:        2016-02-11T14:56:17Z
last-modified:  2016-02-11T14:56:17Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.88 (BLAARKOP)
```

This message is prompting you to update your whois program.
Have you tried to update/upgrade your whois program lately?

Comment: This is not the answer I intended. Sorry.

Comment: @dschinn1001 In that case you should fix your question.